# mysql and PDO simultanious connections

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a mysql and PDO db connection both connecting to the same db with all the same user/pass info open at the same time. Should I see both connections when running the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` in the sql command line?

Comment: @Blazemonger what did you edit here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure, cause PDO and mysql use different drivers and every of them has its own unique session while connecting to MySQL database.

Comment: thats what I was afraid of, no matter what I do it only shows once connection even though neither connection throws an error.

Comment: I assume you are opening both connections in the same page / script?

Comment: there are two different pages but both included in an init.php file